# Converting distances in a track in a coverage plot

Tags: r, bash, awk

I have a track that is of a certain distance. I also have a coordinate file of distances in that track. I now want to know how many times every position in the track has been covered by the coordinate file.

For example, my track has a length of 10 for simplicity, and my coordinate file has the following events:

```
ID START END AMOUNT
1  2     4   1
2  3     7   2
3  3     4   1
4  4     10  1
```

Here we see 4 events, the second event happened twice so needs to be counted twice. The output should be:

```
POS COV
2   1
3   4
4   5
5   3
6   3
7   3
8   1
9   1
10  1
```

This is crazy specific for my purposes but I feel like the solution is dead simple and I am not googling this correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please let us know by which columns we need to calculate distances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `mapply` via base R,

```
as.data.frame(table(unlist(rep(mapply(`:`, df$START, df$END), df$AMOUNT))))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   Var1 Freq
> 1    2    1
> 2    3    4
> 3    4    5
> 4    5    3
> 5    6    3
> 6    7    3
> 7    8    1
> 8    9    1
> 9   10    1
> ```

Breaking down the above:

- `` mapply(`:`, df$START, df$END) ``: Creates the sequences between
  `START` and `STOP`
- `` rep(mapply(`:`, df$START, df$END), df$AMOUNT)) ``: Replicates each sequence by `AMOUNT` times
- `` table(unlist(rep(mapply(`:`, df$START, df$END), df$AMOUNT))) ``: Creates a frequency table
- `as.data.frame`: Wraps it to a data frame (Original output of `table` is a named vector)

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
ID START END AMOUNT
1  2     4   1
2  3     7   2
3  3     4   1
4  4     10  1

$ cat cov.awk
NR > 1 {for (i=1; i<=$4; ++i)
          for (j=$2; j<=$3; ++j) cov[j] += 1}

END {for (i=1; i<=len; ++i)
       if (i in cov) print i, cov[i]}

$ awk -v len=10 -f cov.awk file
2 1
3 4
4 5
5 3
6 3
7 3
8 1
9 1
10 1
```

Comment: I must be missing something, I don't get your output https://pastebin.com/D12hFxvr

Comment: It's because you don't have the header, hence the `NR > 1` is skipping the first line of data. I should have shown the data as I had it. I'll add that now.

Comment: Oh, so silly. Thanks for the clarification, works great now!